# Object reference not set to an instance of an object model fk and virtual field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

This used to work. I upgraded my Entity framework to 6.1.1 today and now I have this error.

I'm getting an object using linq like this:

```
Models.University myUni = DAL.University.GetById(Convert.ToInt16(University.SelectedValue));
lblUniName.Text = myUni.Name;
lblUniLang.Text = myUni.Language.Name;
```

When trying to view the `myUni.Language` is now `null`

This is my model:

```
public int? Language_Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Language_Id")]
public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make sure that the `University` in question does indeed have a reference to `Language` in the database?

Comment: 100% sure it does have a language reference. I've checked it in the DB and also I have an older version of the site running which works as expected.

Comment: Did Proxy-Creation turned off? Lazy-Loading turned off?

Comment: also is there a reason why you are using `Convert.ToInt16` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` where are you assigning `Language_Id` the nullable property value will always be Null unless you explicitly assign it a value..

Comment: @haim770 it was `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` Please post it as an answer and I will mark it as resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Lazy-Loading in not turned-off in your configuration:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)